# Kotlin: Not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

`val color = setting("Color").color().depend(mode) { mode.like("Lightmap") }`

```
class SettingColor(n: String, d: String, val color: ColorMutable) : Setting(n, d)
```

```
abstract class Setting(var name: String, val description: String) {
    fun <T : Setting>depend(vararg dependencies: Setting, resolver: () -> Boolean): T {
        return this as T
    }
    class Builder(
        private val m: Module,
        private val n: String,
        private val d: String
    ) {
        private fun <S : Setting>Module.setup(s: S): S {
              g?.settings?.add(s)
              this.addSetting(s)
              return s
        }
        fun color(color: ColorMutable = ColorMutable.WHITE) = m.setup(SettingColor(n, d, color))
}
```

Problem with the `depend()` method. My IDE says, there are not enough info to infer type of T. However  `color()` method i'm using here instantiates `SettingColor`, which is a direct child of the
`Setting` class, in which `depend()` method is written in.

The only possible solution, which i don't really want to stick to, is to explicitly set type for `depend()` like this:

`val color = setting("Color").color().depend<SettingColor>(mode) { mode.like("Lightmap") }`

UPD: Kotlin version is 1.8.10

Comment: The most viable solution is going to be to remove the generics on the method and to override it in SettingColor to return a SettingColor.  That's as good as it's going to get.